# NonlinearModelFit::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, fitting, complex, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a nonlinear parameter fitting problem as described by Mathematica code below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
 A=Rationalize@1.44928 ;a=Rationalize@0.32161; b=Rationalize@1.27495;
data=Rationalize@{{0.005,0.20021},{0.00778,0.30532},{0.01056,0.42544},{0.01333,0.53054},{0.01622,0.65066},{0.019,0.77078},{0.02178,0.87589},{0.02478,0.98099},{0.02756,1.0861},{0.03033,1.17619},{0.03311,1.28129},{0.03589,1.35637},{0.04156,1.50652},{0.04711,1.65667},{0.05267,1.77679},{0.05822,1.91192},{0.06389,2.01703},{0.06944,2.12213},{0.07489,2.21222},{0.086,2.37739},{0.09133,2.43745},{0.10778,2.64766},{0.12411,2.79781},{0.14044,2.93294},{0.15822,3.05306},{0.17456,3.12814},{0.19089,3.21823},{0.20722,3.27829},{0.22356,3.33835},{0.23989,3.38339},{0.25611,3.42844},{0.27244,3.47348},{0.28878,3.50351},{0.30511,3.51853},{0.32144,3.54856},{0.33778,3.56357},{0.35411,3.57859},{0.37044,3.57859},{0.38667,3.5936},{0.403,3.5936},{0.40544,3.5936},{0.45578,3.60862},{0.50611,3.57859},{0.55656,3.56357},{0.60689,3.53354},{0.65722,3.4885},{0.70756,3.45847},{0.75789,3.42844},{0.80822,3.38339},{0.85867,3.33835}};

 σ[x_?NumberQ]:=(2 A (Exp[a(x^2+2/x-3)]-b Log@(x^2+2/x-2))+NIntegrate[4 p1 (Exp[p2 (t^2+2/t-3)]-p3 Log@(t^2+2/t-2))(t-t^-2)Exp[3(x-t)],{t,1,x}])(x^2-1/x)

nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data,σ[x],{p1,p2,p3},x]
```

but got the following output

> Out[8]= FittedModel[σ[x]]

and error message:

> NonlinearModelFit::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a minimum; it may be a maximum or a saddle point.

I tried to set some initial guesses of the parameters, but got similiar errors.

Is it possible to solve such a problem by `NonlinearModelFit`? How can I use `Differential Evolution` in `NMinimize` without the problem of complex function/evaluation values?

Further error messages like:

> evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the \
>   region with boundaries
>   NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {}. NIntegrate obtained  and  for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: What are your estimated values? I got the code working, but values are way off.

Comment: When estimating $\sigma(x)$ at specific $p_1,p_2,p_3$ values, for example $p_1=A,p_2=a,p_3=b$, I got such errors: `\[Sigma][2] /. {p1 -> A, p2 -> a, p3 -> b}`

Comment: Right after the `ClearAll` statement, I assigned values to $A,a,b$, these are constants; while the parameters to fit are $p_1,p_2,p_3$.

Comment: Those estimates don't seem to be very accurate.

Comment: Even manually, I can't find a fit anywhere near accurate.

Comment: That is why I am asking the possibility of using `Differential Evolution` in `NMinimize`. But `NIntegrate` may act problematic per the numerical evaluation of `\[Sigma][2] /. {p1 -> A, p2 -> a, p3 -> b}`

Comment: You can implement differential evolution in `NonlinearModelFit` using `..., Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}}]`. I gave it a try with your data, but was unable to find a good fit. You can modify the method using standard options with `..., Method -> {NMinimize, 
   Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.9, 
     "CrossProbability" -> 0.1}}]`, or with any other option of `"DifferentialEvolution"`.

Comment: Thank you! `NIntegrate` may not converge for some of the parameters or even gave complex values might be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment.  First one notices that `p2` is the only non-linear parameter.  Because of that one can set `p2` to some value and then just use linear regression to estimate `p1` and `p13=p1*p3` conditional on the value of `p2`.  The only reason for doing this is to avoid (at least potentially) convergence issues with `NonlinearModelFit` as there is an explicit formula for the linear regression parameter estimates and no starting values are needed.

One would create new variables `z1`, `z2`, and `z3` as the numerical integration would only have to be done once for each value of `p2`:

```
x = data[[All, 1]];
p2 = -100
z1 = 2 A (Exp[a (x^2 + 2/x - 3)] - b Log@(x^2 + 2/x - 2)) (x^2 - 1/x);
z2 = Table[(x[[i]]^2 - 1/x[[i]]) NIntegrate[Exp[p2 (t^2 + 2/t - 3)] (t - t^-2) Exp[3 (x[[i]] - t)],
{t, x[[i]], 1}], {i, Length[x]}];
z3 = Table[-4 (x[[i]]^2 - 1/x[[i]]) NIntegrate[
        Log@(t^2 + 2/t - 2) (t - t^-2) Exp[3 (x[[i]] - t)], {t, x[[i]], 1}],
 {i, Length[x]}];
data2 = Transpose[{z1, z2, z3, data[[All, 2]]}];
lm = LinearModelFit[data2, {x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x3}, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]
lm["RSquared"]
```

If a value for `p2` could be found that maximizes `RSquared` or minimizes `AIC`, then that value and the associated values could be plugged in as starting values for `NonlinearModelFit`.

However, a value of `p2 = -500` still doesn't maximize the `RSquared` value (which suggest that `p2` is even smaller than -500) so either I've made some mistake in translating the formulas, the original formulas are wrong, one or more of the constants `A`, `a`, and `b` are wrong, or (which many times happens in practice) the data is not generated from the expected form of the model.